# Touch + Hold then Drag with HTML Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

This is mostly an 'is this possible' type of question, because after a day of testing options, I am not sure that it is.

We have a list of item within a scrollable DIV, each of which needs to be touch draggable. Just turning on drag and drop for each time will break the ability to scroll the list, as a swipe to scroll gets interpreted as a drag event as well. The easiest option if to add a drag handle to each item, but we have very little UI space available on these items, and the powers that be were hoping to not squeeze things even tighter to add a touch hit area for said handle.

The option I am looking into is a 'touch and hold to release'. The user touched and holds the touch for one second, and the item 'unlocks' to be draggable. This sounded easiest enough when I set out, using HammerJS for the Press event, then calling a start for the drag and drop event process. This is not working out however, as none of the browser drag events can be manually started. I can call 'touchstart' with a trigger or dispatchEvent, which will do the setup we need, but no drag events every occur. 'dragstart' normally gets fired as soon as the touchstart occurs, and since I am needing to wait, there is never and dragstart to kick off the process.

I assume the browser's drag and drop events work only under specific circumstances. Triggering dragstart manually wont be a real drag event (its missing all the dataTransfer stuff), and most importantly, nothing actually gets dragged, despite the element being a valid, draggable element. Using an alternate event like 'dragover' works, but since its there was never a real dragstart, there is no actual drag and drop occurring.

Is this just something that browsers do not support short of dropping the HTML drag and drop for javascript? Or is there something I am missing?